# How do I create array with dynamic length rather than slice in golang?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

For example: I want to use reflect to get a slice's data as an array to manipulate it.

```
func inject(data []int) {
    sh := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&data))
    dh := (*[len(data)]int)(unsafe.Pointer(sh.Data))
    printf("%v\n", dh)
}
```

This function will emit a compile error for `len(data)` is not a constant. How should I fix it?

Comment: In c++, I can use `const` variable as the length of array, but golang can not do it for const must be computed when compile.

Comment: You can't. Arrays have a fixed length. Use a slice.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Your question seems like an XY Problem.

Comment: If you already have the slice (whose backing array you'd like to get), you can use the slice to change the elements, you don't need an array for that. You're just complicating things and making your own task more difficult.

Comment: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/): The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem. This leads to enormous amounts of wasted time and energy, both on the part of people asking for help, and on the part of those providing help.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the [@icza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705598/icza)'s comment, you can easily extract the underlying array by using `&data[0]`—assuming `data` is an initialized slice. IOW, there's no need to jump through the hoops here: the address of the first slice's element is actually the address of the first slot in the slice's underlying array—no magic here.

Since taking an address of an element of an array is creating
a reference to that memory—as long as the garbage collector is
concerned—you can safely let the slice itself go out of scope
without the fear of that array's memory becoming inaccessible.

The only thing which you can't really do with the resulting
pointer is passing around the result of dereferencing it.
That's simply because arrays in Go have their length encoded in
their type, so you'll be unable to create a function to accept
such array—because you do not know the array's length in advance.

Now please stop and think.

After extracting the backing array from a slice, you have
a pointer to the array's memory.
To sensibly carry it around, you'll also need to carry around
the array's length… but this is precisely what slices do:
they pack the address of a backing array with the length of the
data in it (and also the capacity).

Hence really I think you should reconsider your problem
as from where I stand I'm inclined to think it's a non-problem
to begin with.

There *are* cases where wielding pointers to the backing arrays
extracted from slices may help: for instance, when "pooling"
such arrays (say, via `sync.Pool`) to reduce memory churn
in certain situations, but these are concrete problems.
If you have a concrete problem, please explain *it,*
not your attempted solution to it—what @Flimzy said.

---

**Update** I think I should may be better explain the

> you can't really do with the resulting
>   pointer is passing around the result of dereferencing it.

bit.

A crucial point about arrays in Go (as opposed to slices)
is that arrays—as everything in Go—are passed around
*by value,* and for arrays that means their data is copied.

That is, if you have

```
var a, b [8 * 1024 * 1024]byte
...
b = a
```

the statement `b = a` would really copy 8 MiB of data.
The same obviously applies to arguments of functions.

Slices sidestep this problem by holding a pointer
to the underlying (backing) array. So a slice value
is a little `struct` type containing
a pointer and two integers.
Hence copying it is really cheap but "in exchange" it
has reference semantics: both the original value and
its copy point to the same backing array—that is,
reference the same data.

I really advise you to read these two pieces,
in the indicated order:

1. https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals
2. https://blog.golang.org/slices